# how to open multiple items in single activity using buttons in android studio

Tags: android

I have 15 Buttons in Main Activity, And i know how to open new activity on button click. All 15 buttons contain different items, I want to open each button items in single activity. Is it possible to do that, If yes could i know how.

Comment: yes possible !!!!

Comment: paste your code here so we can figure out about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. Read this documentation-
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html